# restrict access with htaccess in web server

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, webserver

I am using wordpress and I have a folder under wp-content/ structured as:

```
folder
  |-folder1
       |-file.pdf
  |-folder2
  |-.htaccess
```

I have all PDF files distributed within subfolders in the folder directory. I don't want all files inside the folder to be accessed directly. so I place the code in .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

but this does not seem to prevent that purpose. when I enter this url: http://mysite.come/wp-content/folder/folder1/file.pdf, the file still can be downloaded, which it shouldn't. what seems to be wrong here? thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **.htaccess** file sets directives to the current folder and sub-folders.

**important:**

- make sure that you have enabled *[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) All* for that directory in the webserver configuration (if it is set to *None* change it to *All* and restart the web server).
- if you want to override a directive set in an parent folder you have to place a **.htaccess** file in every folder you want to override (including the directives you want to override).

Comment: are u sure? theoretically, if you can't access the parent folder, you should not be able to access its children folders.

Comment: correct. children folder inherit directives from parent folders. I rewrote the answer to improve understanding... sorry about that.

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know where I can enable the AllowOverride All? thanks for help again.

Comment: include the webserver as a tag to your question ;) you will only be able to edit the configuration if you have root access to your server. on linux with apache you usually find the main config file in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf